# Find third point in right triangle

Tags: mathematics

I need to get position marked as green X.
I have the helicopter's world position and the player's world position. I want X to always have an angle of 90 degrees.
Player heading is ignored.
How can I obtain the position X.

[image]

Comment: Seems like that question finds the angle rather the position.

Comment: If you know the angle, you can calculate the position: `x = cos(a) * r`, `y = sin(a) * r`

Comment: Which angle do you want to be 90 degrees: PXH or XPH ?

Comment: Initially, I wanted PXH to be 90 degrees, but now I'm not too sure. Overall, what I'm trying to do is have the heli fly to a position X and then orbit counter-clockwise around the player. So would it be better to have PXH or XPH as 90 degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

First we need to calculate rotation of vector from P to H. *(Here, V.y means y component of vector V, similarly for V.x)*

[image]

Next, we need to increment the angle found by 90 degrees. *(You can decrement by 90 degrees too, that will give you another point which is also correct.)*

[image]

Now we have the polar coordinates for the point T relative to P: (theta, r).

All we need to do is to convert this to Cartesian coordinates. *(Here, dot is multiplication)*

[image]

Now, we can calculate the cartesian position of the point T, and add over the position of P to make it relative to the origin (0,0).

[image]

---

**Footnote:** You may want to use `Atan2` in your code instead of `Atan` for finding arctangent.

Comment: you set TPH as 90 deg angle (according to your first image), but I think he want PTH to be 90 deg.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with 2D positions, this is relatively straight forward, all you need to do is get the vector from the player to the helicopter (heliPos - playerPos) and then rotate it 90 degrees (Almost all libraries able to handle vectors should have rotation built in, but if you don't have access to one this can also be done via swapping the X and Y and negating either one, each negation option will give you one of the two 90 degree rotations).

Once you've done that, add the rotated vector to the player's position to get the third point of your triangle.  If you need the third point to be a specific distance from the player, such as putting it on a circle around the player, you simply need to normalize the rotated vector and then multiply it by your desired length before adding it to the player position to get your world coordinate.